# What does this reference mean?

Tags: reference-request

I saw this in [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/89791&ved=2ahUKEwiN1bbQwrPgAhXJM48KHQKrD_gQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw0f-aZ1hCiY_BxqeawNAhlP&ampcf=1) fatwa,

```
al-Silsilah al-Da’eefah (1/270-274)
```

What does this mean, if it indicates any page of a book, can you please post it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a work by Nasiruddin al-Albani, the numbers in the brackets with a slash usually mean a volume and page numbers. [Here](https://archive.org/stream/WAQdaifaa/daifaa01#page/n270/mode/2up) is a scanned copy.

Comment: Sadly, I'm not an arab.